# Can't access passwords from Keychain Access

Tags: macos, mac, keychain

When I try to access a stored password in my login keychain, either using Keychain Access from the relevant GUI or the security command from the command line the following happens:

- I type my password when the relevant dialog appers.
- After I hit the "Allow" (or the "Always allow" button the password is not shown and there is no feedback whatsoever on what happened wrong. The mouse turns into the spinning wheel only when I hover it over the main window of Keychain access. The dialog box stays there unless I press the "Deny" Button.

Same thing happens when I try to access a password from the command line or when I try to unlock a certain keychain from the keychain GUI. In general it happens when the allow/deny dialog box comes up.

An image of where the process gets stuck is shown below, although it's not very descriptive.

[image]

Restarting the application didn't do any good. Restarting the system made the application work for a limited amount of time.

Is there any way to bypass this dialog box or get my passwords in raw form?
The model is Macbook Pro, and the OS version is Yosemite 10.11.3

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you have screen sharing enabled?  That will do it.

Comment: If it's on, turn off Screen Sharing and try this again.

Comment: nope.. screen sharing is disabled.